# accessing field symbol that is defined runtime ABAP

Tags: abap

I am currently working on a dynamic report for which i have to write some dynamic queries and i am stuck at a place. Please, it would be great if anyone can suggest me s way out. Bellow i have tried to explain what i am doing and where i am stuck. Thanks.
Defining 2 field symbol

```
<o_fs> TYPE table,
<owa_fs> type any.
```

Dynamically creating a internal table for o_fs

```
CALL METHOD cl_alv_table_create=>create_dynamic_table
EXPORTING
it_fieldcatalog = it_cat
IMPORTING
ep_table = d_ref2.
ASSIGN d_ref2->* TO <o_fs>.
```

then i fill data in the o_fs
After that i want to add a value to one of the field of o_fs
LOOP AT

```
<O_FS> ASSIGNING <OWA_FS>.
 *<owa_fs>-columnname = 'value to be added'.
 IF SY-TABIX = INDEX.
 MODIFY (p_vtab) From <OWA_FS>.
 COMMIT WORK.
 ENDIF.
```

the line which is marked * is giving me an compile time error that "The data object "" has no structure and therefore no component called 'COLUMNNAME'. called 'COLUMNNAME'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When syntax-checking, the system doesn't know whether the field-symbol is structured or not. You have to assign the structure component to another field symbol. See [ASSIGN COMPONENT ...](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/index.htm?file=abapassign_mem_area_dynamic_dobj.htm) command for that.

Putting the command into your example:

```
ASSIGN COMPONENT 'COLUMNMAME' OF STRUCTURE <owa_fs> TO <another_fs>.
IF sy-subrc = 0.
  <another_fs> = 'value to be added'.
ENDIF.
```

`<another_fs>` can be `ANY` type.